# How can I send SMS to mobile in local environment?

Tags: php, localhost, sms

I want to send a SMS (text message) using php to a mobile. The application would be deployed in localhost. I'm from Romania,Europe. Let me know if any live freeware api to implement this. I can go for paid versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twilio, Nexmo etc for sending SMS, even through localhost.
Some of them provide you with free testing credit but that is only for testing purpose.

You can use their API, 
see:-https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api for more reference.

Read the docs its simple to implement.

Comment: <?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$account_sid = 'added';
$auth_token = 'added';
$twilio_number = "+15017122661";
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);                                                  
 $client->messages->create(
    // Where to send a text message (your cell phone?)
    '+added_myphonenumber',
    array(
        'from' => $twilio_number,
        'body' => 'I sent this message in under 10 minutes!'
    )
);

?>

Comment: Warning: require(C:\wamp64\www\proiect-de-licenta/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\proiect-de-licenta\indextest.php on line 2

Comment: Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www\proiect-de-licenta/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\proiect-de-licenta\indextest.php on line 2

Comment: You can download lumen framework to run this code, don't forget to run composer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below URL for it:
https://rapidapi.com/dimashirokov/api/Plivo
First check with curl example so you get proper response for it.
Below is code for curl example :

```
$api_key = '';
$from = 'From name';
$to = '123456789';
$message = 'Test SMS';  
$target_url="";
$post = array('from' => $from,'to'=>$to,"message"=>$message,"api-key"=>$api_key);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```

You need to add appropriate data for above code so you get response.

Comment: can you send me a complete code which sends sms ? (i will change only the phone number), I tried this cod from above,i also changed $to='my phone number here', but nothing happens, no error, no SMS

Answer (score 0):

You can use SMSLink API availabile on https://www.smslink.ro for sending SMS in Romania. You can choose from HTTP(S) GET / POST, SOAP / WSDL or JSON API, or even Mail to SMS.